# SHA256 in C# on Windows vs. openssl on unix

Tags: c#, unix, openssl, sha256

I am computing a hash on unix with the following:

```
echo -n "Test123" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | openssl base64
```

This gives:

```
9JKwVu6ULKgdcQq8I2QugjqDhkvHgiqq8bsBtM7PNGc=
```

I have the following C# code:

```
string enc;
using(SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed())
{
    enc = Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test123")));
}
```

And this gives:

```
2bX1jws4GYKTIxhIoUB09Z66PoJZQ+y+hq5R8dnx9I4=
```

I do not understand why these are not identical?

Comment: This is a little confusing.  Your title says "SHA512" but your examples seem to be for SHA256.  Your outputs also appear to be a 32-byte hashes.

Comment: @totalfreakingnoob Sorry about the typo in the title

Comment: Problem is the same regardless of the digest output size

Comment: Both statements yield 2bX1jws4GYKTIxhIoUB09Z66PoJZQ+y+hq5R8dnx9I4= for me.

Comment: @Jamey I assumed the .NET version was correct.  I wonder what is going on with my openssl?  It is actually an AIX box that I am running on right now

Comment: I'm on a Mac with OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016.

Comment: I've tried with multiple _OpenSSL_ versions (0.9.8, 1.0.1, 1.0.2) on various platforms and architectures (including _AIX_) and yielded the same result. What's the `openssl version -a` output on your _AIX_ box?

Comment: Thank you all!!  I hopped on a separate AIX box and the command is working fine there!  Here is the ridiculous part: the `openssl version -a` command returns the same exact thing on both boxes

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013, built on: Wed Jul 8 04:44:10 CDT 2015, platform: aix-xlc_r

Comment: Any way to determine if there is perhaps something wacky going on with the `echo` command? @Jamey @CristiFati

Comment: I remove the `-n` from the `echo` call and now they both return the same string.  However, now an extra line-feed is part of the input string (which is unacceptable)

Comment: Is there some funky locale set on the faulty machine? (As I doubt that it would influence the result). I would try to see which command messes up the result (I'm almost sure that it's the 2nd). I assume that _OpenSSL_ is not custom built (and the sources modified) on that machine. Worst case reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I knew this had to be something stupid and it was.  On the problematic box I was logged in as `root` so I was on a K-shell.  From there it doesn't handle the `echo -n` the same way as from a C-shell.  Leaving this here because I will probably have this problem again in five years :)